# How to change QS structure in Django?

Tags: django, dictionary, django-queryset

Currently, my QS is like this:

```
Great Expectations Bookstore 1 $8.99
Great Expectations Bookstore 2 $12.99
Great Expectations Bookstore 3 $6.99
Tales from the Crypt Bookstore 1 $5.99
The Sisterhood of the Traveling Pants Bookstore 3 $8.99
Oprah: The Icon Bookstore 2 $6.99
Oprah: The Icon Bookstore 3 $9.99
```

I'd like to create a QS or just a dictionary that I could pass to my view that looks like this:

```
Great Expectations, 3, {price1: $6.99, price2: $8.99, price3: $12.99}
Tales from the Crypt, 1, {price1: $5.99}
The Sisterhood of the.., 1, {price1: $6.99}
Oprah: The Icon, 2, {price1: $6.99, price2: $9.99}
```

Basically I don't care about the bookstore that it's sold at and want to compress the QS into just book titles with a dictionary or tuple of prices. It would be preferable if I could order those prices from min to max in the dictionary.

I've tried to do this with .annotate() but cannot get it to work with all prices, just minimum or maximum. Am I missing something - is there an easy way to do this?

Added model, passing no other model to the view.

```
class Books(models.Model):
    bookid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, help_text='Book ID')
    booktitle = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    bookstore = models.ForeignKey("Bookstores", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
     ordering = ['bookid', 'bookstore', 'price']

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.booktitle}
```

Comment: Show your models.

Comment: Added primary model.

Comment: First of all, no you haven't; `book title` is not a valid field name, and `self.book` in the str model refers to a field that doesn't exist. And secondly, you should show all relevant models.

Comment: This is the primary model. Yes I have changed the names of the items.

Answer (score 0):

Your models don't make much sense, which is the cause of your problem. Currently you have an individual Book record for each book in a bookstore, even if it's the same book available at a different price in a different store. What you need is a single model for each book, with a many-to-many relationship to bookstore and a through table that stores the price. So:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(...)

class BookPrice(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey('Book')
    store = models.ForeignKey('Bookstore')
    price = models.DecimalField(...)

class Bookstore(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    books = models.ManyToManyField('Book', through='BookPrice')
```

Now, even with this structure, there's no way to directly get the result you want, but you can do this:

```
BookPrice.objects.values('book__title', 'price').order_by('book__title', 'price')
```

Comment: Think of bookstore as an irrelevant field. There are just multiple prices. Basically  I have multiple rows, I just want to compress the data set. It doesn't need to remain a QS.